# Disk Utility Error Message - Missing EFI + MediaKit

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Previously setup was with 2 partitions, one for normal use while the other had the Lion Install ESD on it, used when I installed some time ago. The other day my machine suddenly shutdown and when I started it, it stated that the Lion Install ESD partition was corrupted.

I created a new Lion Install ESD partition and made a clean install (I was going to do so anyway).

My machine is booting fine, but it acts funny in the Disk Utility. First, an overview of my disk:

- 0: GUID_partition_scheme (*250.1GB / disk0)
- 1: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD (230.0 GB / disk0s1)
- 2: Apple_Boot Recovery HD (650.0 MB / disk0s5)
- 3: EFI (209.7 MB / disk0s4)

However if I attempt to "Verify Disk" on my disk (not on a specific partition) via the Disk Utility the following error is shown:

> This disk doesn't contain an EFI system partition. If you want to start up your computer with this disk or include it in a RAID set,
>   back up your data and partition this disk.

Even more strange is when I attempt to let the "Macintosh HD" use maximum space on the disk. It is currently sized at 230GB, but if I use the Disk Utility to increase it to say 231GB it reports the following error:

> Partition failed with the error: MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation.

However, the space is clearly unused. And if I simply drag the partition down to use all the space the error will not prompt but nothing will happen.

In the time between my first install of Lion and the recent shutdown I had installed rEFIt after attempting to run Ubuntu, however it was quickly uninstalled again with no issues in the following months.

So, any clue what is going on with my disk?

Comment: For at least one build of Lion: the distribution (ESD) was **not** applicable to all Lion-capable Macs.
Is the affected Mac the one where Install Mac OS X Lion.app was used to obtain the distribution?

Comment: Your EFI partition needs to be at index 1, where your Apple_HFS Macintosh HD is.

Comment: Your EFI partition needs to be at index 1. I just asked a question about how to do this because I have no idea http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134359/creating-a-efi-partition