# Creating a EFI partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, efi

I have been having trouble installing OS X Mavericks and I think I found the problem. It told me I couldn't boot up with Macintosh HD, so I verified my disk and I got this error: This disk doesn't contain an EFI system partition

So I figured out I can create one like this (tell me if I'm wrong): `sudo gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0` from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/how-to-fix-broken-efi-partition), but they also said the "index" must be 1, so I can't have anything at that index.

I ran `diskutil list` and this is the output:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            233.0 GB   disk0s1
   2:                 Linux Swap                         4.0 GB     disk0s2
```

So I need to figure out how to move the indexes of Macintosh HD and that Linux Swap thing to indexes 2 and 3 instead of 1 and 2.

I don't know if this can be done without wiping and formatting my hard drive which I don't want to do, but if it can I would love to know how. Thanks!

By the way I'm on OS X mountain lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually EFI is on your Macintosh HD. It's likely still there, but not used due to messed up settings. This very easy to fix:

- Boot into a Recovery partition, DVD, or USB drive. Using the installation media that came with your device will suffice.
- Once loaded, you'll be presented an interface like:

[image: Recovery Mode Utilities]

- Close this window, and you'll be prompted to choose between `Startup disk`, `Cancel`, and `Restart`.
- Select `Startup Disk`. The mere act of opening this utility with run the appropriate [bless command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/bless.8.html) in the background, repairing your EFI setup.
- Select `Macintosh HD`
- Restart
- Come back to Ask Different and up vote this successful answer :D

Comment: I accidently deleted my startup partition... (Ya I know that was dumb) so how to I make a DVD? Can it just be a normal mountain lion installer?

Comment: I also have a Linux 13.04 install dvd that I could enter some commands on if necessary but I doubt that'd help. I think the Linux partition I used to have messed the EFI up.

Comment: Yes, any OS X install media or recovery media will work

Comment: Sorry I now see you said it could be an installer, but my computer came installed with snow leopard, so do I have to use that or should I use mountain lion (which I am using I fixed that in the question) or does it not matter? Sorry that I'm making this confusing, I will defiantly up vote your answer if this works and select it as successful

Comment: As far as I recall, all modern OS X versions have nearly identical installation/recovery modes, so your SL disk will work.

Comment: Ok thanks! I need to get a USB/DVD with enough space but once I do I'll try this.

Comment: Don't you have the installation media that came with your Mac? If not, you can always ask a friend

Comment: No, my Mac with Snow Leopard already installed, it may have came with a DVD but I wouldn't know where it is. I got it like about 4 years ago. But thats true, I can already ask a friend.

Comment: I found a 10.6 DVD, and this didn't work ;( I think I'm gonna just have to backup everything and reinstall OS X.

Comment: Boot the disk, and check if `/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi` exists from the terminal (e.g. `ls /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi`). When you say "didn't work," you really have to elaborate more lol. Did you get the startup disk selection screen, and did your boot partition appear on the list?

Comment: No I did everything you said to do and it went fine, but I still don't have/see an EFI partition and can't upgrade to Mavericks. And yes that file does exist.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "EFI" partition. EFI is stored on every bootable partition (for OS X, it's in the location I mentioned above), and the default location is stored in the Mac's NVRAM (which can be seen with `nvram -p`).

Comment: The next step I suppose is to reinstall the OS. You won't have to format the disk, and your home directories will stay intact

Comment: The Mountain Lion installer app doesn't work, because it says it's unable to boot with, just like a Mavericks installer. Would making a 10.8 installer work (I don't want to use my 10.6 one, not that it really matters), or would it give me the same error?

Comment: The error would probably be the same. I suppose backing up, formatting and installing anew would help. 10.6 has access to the Mac App Store, so installing Mavericks from it would be just as easy as ML, without having to make an ML boot disk

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll go ahead and mark this answer as correct because you helped my out enough to get to the right solution. Thanks!!